# How to change Go modules path?

Tags: go, go-modules

I got a github repo **github.com/user/somerepo**.

I init it by doing `go mod init **github.com/user/somerepo**`

I need to change this dependecy and make it point to another github repository. Let say : **github.com/user/a-different-repo**.

Is there any go command that can update all the import statements in all the files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `go mod edit -replace` is your friend for that.

From the doc ([Source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/modcmd/edit.go#L58)) :

> The -replace=old[@v]=new[@v] flag adds a replacement of the given
>   module path and version pair. If the @v in old@v is omitted, a
>   replacement without a version on the left side is added,

Here is the important part :

> which **applies to all versions of the old module path**. If the @v in
>   new@v is omitted, the new path should be a local module root
>   directory, not a module path. Note that -replace overrides any
>   redundant replacements for old[@v], so omitting @v will drop existing
>   replacements for specific versions.

Here is the [AddReplace func](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/fca286bed3ed0e12336532cc711875ae5b3cb02a/src/cmd/vendor/golang.org/x/mod/modfile/rule.go#L734) which is responsible for the replacement.

Now to achieve it, each of your repository must be mapped to your GOPATH.
A little recall on GOPATH :

When you want a repository to become a "go gettable" package you should map this repository to your GOPATH.

[As explained here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH#repository-integration-and-creating-go-gettable-projects) when you do `go get`, it will first looks up in your `$GOPATH` an take the latest version of the package (or the specific version if you specified it in your go.mod file)

Then you can achieve your edit by doing this command :

```
go mod edit -replace github.com/UserA/foo@v0.1=github.com/UserA/bar@v0.1
```

Another way (and maybe a better one) is to do this inside the go.mod file, like so :

```
  module foo.bar                        

  replace github.com/UserA/foo => github.com/UserA/bar

  require (   
  github.com/UserA/foo v0.0.1
 )
```

Of course, this will work only if each repository is mapped into your GOPATH.

See also here for further explanation: [when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive)

Comment: I have tried that but I'm getting  **: unversioned new path must be local directory** as a response.

Comment: How do you manage your gopath ? Did you pull the repository in your local file directory ?

Comment: @prophecy : i update my answer with an explanation on how to achieve this....please be sure that your repository is mapped to the GOPATH

Comment: I get the error even when pointing to a valid local directory. I have to use the fully qualified directory path for it not to error: `/home/user/code/github.com/company/repo` instead of `github.com/company/repo` (both a valid github repo and local directory)

Comment: @fIwJlxSzApHEZIl : as I mentioned, this might be because your location (/home/user/code/) : is not mapped into your GOPATH. Can you check ?

Comment: @jossefaz interestingly enough if you have a local relative path that mirrors a github import, say, `$GOPATH/github.com/org/repo` (a folder) and the same exact import `github.com/org/repo` (a remote github repo) - `go mod edit -replace` can't differentiate between the two. However, if you do `go mod edit -replace github.com/org/repo=/home/user/github.com/org/repo`  then you will be fine. Essentially, `go mod edit -replace` cannot differentiate between an ambiguous relative local path `github.com/org/repo` (the folder) and `github.com/org/repo` (the github repo).

Comment: All of my problems were fixed when I did `go mod edit -replace github.com/org/repo=/home/user/work/github.com/org/repo` aka using a fully qualified local folder path. This helps the go compiler know that the replace is targeting a local folder and not a remote github repo.

Answer (score 9):

`go mod edit -module github.com/user/a-different-repo`