# Cannot access Golang import from my private repository

Tags: go, github

very new to Golang, so I'm sure I am missing something here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have started a new Go project and am attempting to import modules from other packages in my project. To start, I created a new organization under my personal account in Github, let's call it "Rainbow-Coloring-Books", added a repository to the organization called "api", and added + committed some basic Go code.

I have generated a personal access token, and updated my git config to include my git info alongside the PAT.

However, when I try to import modules from my repo, I get the following error when I run a go mod tidy:

```
go: finding module for package github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api/internal/service/user
go: finding module for package github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api/internal/handler/user
go: downloading github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api v0.0.0-20230324230419-1f509a56d7dc
rainbowcoloringbooks/cmd/server imports
        github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api/internal/handler/user: github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api@v0.0.0-20230324230419-1f509a56d7dc: verifying module: github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api@v0.0.0-20230324230419-1f509a56d7dc: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/!rainbow-!coloring-!books/api@v0.0.0-20230324230419-1f509a56d7dc: 404 Not Found
        server response:
        not found: github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api@v0.0.0-20230324230419-1f509a56d7dc: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/5b2a00aa68931b5d9107e6e4b2650ff812770ef5d19fc84a0904a0cb32002eed: exit status 128:
                fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
        Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
        If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
rainbowcoloringbooks/cmd/server imports
        github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api/internal/service/user: github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api@v0.0.0-20230324230419-1f509a56d7dc: verifying module: github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api@v0.0.0-20230324230419-1f509a56d7dc: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/!rainbow-!coloring-!books/api@v0.0.0-20230324230419-1f509a56d7dc: 404 Not Found
        server response:
        not found: github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api@v0.0.0-20230324230419-1f509a56d7dc: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/5b2a00aa68931b5d9107e6e4b2650ff812770ef5d19fc84a0904a0cb32002eed: exit status 128:
                fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
        Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
        If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

The directory of my code is as follows:

```
api/
├── cmd/
│   └── server/
│       └── main.go
├── docker/
├── docs/
├── infrastructure/
├── kubernetes/
├── pkg/
└── internal/
    ├── app/
    ├── handler/
    ├── repository/
    └── service/
```

and in main.go I have these imports:

```
import (
    userHandler "github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api/internal/handler/user"
    userService "github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api/internal/service/user"
)
```

The above URLs used in the imports lead to a 404 page on github when trying to visit in the browser, and the URLs are the following when I navigate manually through the UI, but I have tried these imports which didn't work, and just didn't look right to me:

```
import (
    userService github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api/blob/main/internal/service/user
    userHandler github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api/blob/main/internal/handler/user
)
```

The go.mod files that I am using is as follows:

```
module rainbowcoloringbooks

go 1.20

require github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0

require (
    github.com/go-playground/locales v0.14.1 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/universal-translator v0.18.1 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/validator/v10 v10.12.0 // indirect
    github.com/leodido/go-urn v1.2.2 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.7.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.6.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.8.0 // indirect
)
```

I am curious if there is perhaps something at the organization / repo level that I need to do to allow access, possibly with a PAT? The PAT is just attached to my personal github, but the organization was created through my personal account, I am a member, and I have all permissions needed / can read and write to the repo no problem.

Been spinning my wheels on this one for a while, any assistance is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Where in your project is the `go.mod` file and what are its contents? If you don't know what I'm asking, then please read: [How To Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/code).

Comment: Just updated with go mod - thanks!

Comment: Given the module's name, and assuming the go.mod file is located in the `api/` directory, your imports should look like this: `import "rainbowcoloringbooks/internal/handler/user"`

Comment: Thanks very much! I was thinking that the imports had to be from the github repo, and could not be local ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking that the imports had to be from the github repo, and could not be local

Your `go.mod` "[module path](https://go.dev/ref/mod#module-path)" should describe both what the module does and where to find it.

So it would very well be `github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api`, using [`go mod edit`](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-edit), as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62243083/6309).

```
go mod edit -module github.com/Rainbow-Coloring-Books/api
```

Your imports would still begin with `api/`, because the module path is a prefix of the import path for each package within the module.